# Character creator in Python issue

Tags: python, python-3.2

I'm having serious trouble solving hat seems like a really basic problem and I don't know why it won't work.

Basically, I'm making a character creator for a text based game and there's one part where you need to choose one of three character types. However if I type a correct or incorrect character type it still just gives me the option of entering it again.

I'm using python 3.2

```
def choose_mech_type():
    mecha_type = input("""
Choose mecha type:
Marine
Flight
Ground
""")

    if mecha_type == ("marine"):
        head = ("m.head.basic")
        body = ("m.body.basic")
        back = ("m.back.basic")
        arms = ("m.arms.basic")
        hands = ("m.hands.basic")
        legs = ("m.head.basic")
        feet = ("m.feet.basic")

    if mecha_type == ("flight"):
        head = ("f.head.basic")
        body = ("f.body.basic")
        back = ("f.back.basic")
        arms = ("f.arms.basic")
        hands = ("f.hands.basic")
        legs = ("f.head.basic")
        feet = ("f.feet.basic")

    if mecha_type == ("ground"):
        head = ("g.head.basic")
        body = ("g.body.basic")
        back = ("g.back.basic")
        arms = ("g.arms.basic")
        hands = ("g.hands.basic")
        legs = ("g.head.basic")
        feet = ("g.feet.basic")

    if mecha_type != ("ground") or ("marine") or ("flight"):
        choose_mech_type()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the code is that the following line is always true:

```
if mecha_type != ("ground") or ("marine") or ("flight"):
```

The proper way to check this logic is:

```
if mecha_type not in ["ground", "marine", "flight"]:
```

Another major problem is that once you are inside that if statement, you recursively call the function. Instead of doing that, that you should use a loop that exits when it has valid input.

```
def choose_mech_type():
    while True:     
        mecha_type = input("""
Choose mecha type:
Marine
Flight
Ground
""")
        if mecha_type in ["ground", "marine", "flight"]:
            return mecha_type
```